# Curl is Not Working in Windows OS ,using PHP5.6.30

Tags: curl, php-5.6

I am Using widows OS , and also i am using **PHP Version 5.6.30** , and i copied `libssh2.dll` to apache/bin folder.and also i copied `libeay32.dll`,`libssh2.dll`,`ssleay32.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32`.but still i am getting this **error**- `Call to undefined function curl_init()` and i am not able to see cURL enable in `phpinfo()`.
My code is bellow-

```
  <?php
   $url = 'http://localhost/CurlTest/index.php';
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   echo curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Did you enable the extension in php.ini?

Comment: yes i did that one ...